# How to display a URL as a clickable link in KIbana 4 discovery

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have tweets indexed in ES and displayed in Kibana. Tweet data has some URLs. Like entities.media.expanded_url, or entities.urls.expanded_url. How to make these to display as clickable link in discovery panel?
I went to the index setting and changed format form default to UR or image in case of image but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You have the possibility to format strings as URLs with Kibana 4. To do that, go to `Settings`, select your index and edit the field you want to show as a clickable URL (click over the button under `controls`).

[image: Index field example]

If you change the default format to URL, it should show links in the discover page.

[image: Change format to URL]

Comment: This is exactly what I do. But it is still not showing as a link. Maybe because URLs part of the tweet data ind not indexed properly. I get this warning "Objects in arrays are not well supported".

Comment: @IgorK. can you put an example of your data, plz?

Comment: OK. it works for this part of tweet
{
....
 "user": {
   ....
      "url": "http://nextgengr.com",
   ....
}
But does not work for:
{
....
  "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "urls": [
          {
            "url": "https://t.co/HRQ9FpTzvY",
            "expanded_url": "http://vrl.ht/6E022",
            "display_url": "vrl.ht/6E022",
            "indices": [
              39,
              62
            ]
          }
        ],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
      }
...
for expanded URL

Comment: @Pigueiras What do you mean by "go to Settings, select your index and edit the field"?  I am using Kibana 4.0 (in Amazon Elasticsearch Service), and when I go to Settings and select the index, there is just an inert table listing the fields, with no way to "edit the field".

Comment: @KevinPauli I edited the answer, there should be a button under controls to edit the field. I never tried the Amazon ES Service, so I don't know if they have different settings on their Kibana or not, but I guess it should be the standard one.

Comment: @Pigueiras I still don't see any controls link.  I think it must simply not be available in Kibana 4.0 which is all what Amazon provides at this time.  I installed Kibana 4.4 locally, and indeed there are edit controls there.  So I suppose AWS users must just wait.